# Aurelia refresh property dependencies

Tags: aurelia

Validate if checkbox should be displayed in html page:

```
get canPerformCommand() {
    let r = false;
    let valids = ['Success', 'Error'];

    if (this.requests.length == 0) return false;

    if (valids.indexOf(this.myresult[0].requestStatus) > 0) {
        r = true;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Html page:

```
<span if.bind="canPerformCommand" class="panel-heading-buttons">
    <button click.trigger="confirm()">Confirm</button>
</span>
```

Search:

```
    return this.myService.getRequests()
        .then(data => {
            this.requests = data

            //Somehow refresh canPerformCommand here?
        });
```

`this.requests` will be empty on first page load, resulting in `canPerformCommand = false`. 
I want to refresh `canPerformCommand` when using the search function.

Currently `canPerformCommand` will not refresh itself after a search has been done.

**How do I refresh `canPerformCommand` after search using Property Dependencies?**

Comment: Maybe computedFrom is the answer? 

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-computed-properties/1

Comment: In the end, were you able to get this solved?  What worked for you?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced:

```
if (valids.indexOf(this.myresult[0].requestStatus) > 0) {
    r = true;
}
```

With

```
if (valids.includes(this.requests[0].requestStatus)) {
   r = true;
}
```

And now it works. I was using the indexOf function on other pages aswell, and strangely enough it worked on most of them. Must have been something wrong in my model.

Also, I agree that it would be better to use computedFrom.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

The easiest and most logical solution would be to change `canPerformCommand` into two separate entities -- a flag variable and a function.  Make the flag variable be `canPerformCommand` and keep the `if.bind=canPerformCommand` but change the name of your function to `updateCanPerformCommand()` so that you can easily call this function from your `return this.myService.getRequests()` `.then` function.

**Details:**

Set up your view-model like this:

```
export class App { // <-- (or whatever yours is called)
  canPerformCommnad = false;

  constructor() {
    // ...
  }

  updateCanPerformCommand() {
    let r = false;
    let valids = ['Success', 'Error'];

    if (this.requests.length == 0) {
      this.canPerformCommand = false;
    } else if (valids.indexOf(this.myresult[0].requestStatus) > 0) {
      this.canPerformCommand = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change `myresult` to `requests` in the `canPerformCommand` getter:

```
get canPerformCommand() {
    let r = false;
    let valids = ['Success', 'Error'];

    if (this.requests.length == 0) return false;

    if (valids.indexOf(this.requests[0].requestStatus) > 0) {
        r = true;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Since this getter will be dirty checked by Aurelia, it will be called every 200ms. To avoid that, you can add a `computedFrom` decorator:

```
import {computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyClass {

....

    @computedFrom('requests')
    get canPerformCommand() { ....
```